# Combining surveys with distinct analytical weights in Stata

Tags: stata, survey, weighted-average, crosstable

I have a dataset which combine 14 household surveys in 14 countries. Each survey was conducted in different years and each survey has a household weight variable that only specifies to this country's context (data structure is the same across 14 countries).

Now I merged them and tried to cross tabulate the country and gender_area (four types of value: male_rural, female_rural, male_urban, female_urban) variable with weights (tab country gender [aw=hhweight], m). But I found that such a cross-tabulation would create weird values for some of the countries.

For example, if I add one if condition by the end of the tab (tab country gender [aw=hhweight] if abc==1, m), some country (KHM, NPL) 's row total would be greater than their original row total without the condition. But in this dataset, a condition would give a smaller subsample. If I don't add the weight (tab country gender, m), there is no such a problem. If I just tab one country with weight, there is no such a problem either.

So I wonder if there is any way for me to compare all countries with weight. I am not that familiar with survey data reference in Stata (svyset, strata, etc).

[image]

I tried to refer to the book *Applied Survey Data Analysis*, but it seems that it doesn't contain methodology to deal with such a combination.

Comment: No code presented here and no precise programming problem. The question seems more about statistical strategy to me.

Comment: Correction: there is some code here.